# Stop Maven's Update at Eclipse from changing my encoding settings

Tags: eclipse, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1, eclipse-neon

Every time i Update my project at Eclipse, i see at my git files that the file `.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` are changed from **ISO-8859-1** (which my project uses) to **UTF-8**.

I have already changed at eclipse's preference to **ISO-8859-1** and the problem continues.

Comment: How is that related to maven? If there is a pom.xml involved that may change the encoding of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the encoding in the pom:

```
   <project>
      ...
      <properties>
          <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>
      ...
   </project>
```

Maybe UTF-8 is defined somewhere to be the default if this property is missing.

Comment: That's right. After define the encoding in the pom and updating the maven project, same file changed to our main encoding. Thank you.